# Platforms Supported by the API and Response Compression

Tags: support, faq, api, json, gzip

### What platforms are supported for use with the Stack Exchange API?

In short, anything that can make a `GET` request to the API servers and supports [JSON](http://json.org/)/JSONP & [GZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip). (JavaScript, Python, PHP, Java, C#, etc., etc.)

All [responses from the API will be compressed with GZIP (default) or DEFLATE.](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression)
The `Content-Encoding` header will be set appropriately, but be aware that some proxies will strip this header (along with the corresponding `Accept-Encoding` header) so its presence should not be relied upon.

All returned values will be JSON encoded.  The API does support the `jsonp` parameter for cross-domain requests.

### Why is GZIP support required?

GZIP is 17 years old, and has been part of the HTTP 1.1 standard for 11 years.  Its built into all modern browsers, its [source is freely available](http://www.gzip.org/#sources), and [it's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) [a](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) [part](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html) [of](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/index.html) [all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) [popular](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) languages/platforms.

Not GZIP'ing (more generally, compressing) wastes bandwidth, and [reduces performance](http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_3.html).